# Lucene.Net Name Ambiguity because of CaSe in VB.NET

Tags: lucene.net, ambiguity

I'm working on a vb.net project and I'm getting a compiler error because of the lucene.net library.

There are properties as follows

```
[Obsolete]  // Please use TotalHits instead
totalHits

TotalHits
```

Now the issue is that vb.net is case insensitive in this regard, so it's recognizing both properties and not allowing my to build the project.

Is there a way to circumvent this issue without recompiling the code myself and removing the obsolete properties?

Comment: rolling back to v2.9.2.2 from v2.9.4.1 has temporarily solved this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that!  If it's any consolation, it is something that we're working on.  CLS Compliance, where fixing naming is top priority for VB.NET support, is targeted for the next release, Lucene.NET 3.0.3.  The current code (unreleased) can be found [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/branches/Lucene.Net.3.0.3/).  Those properties are from the `TopDocs` class, and I specifically remember making that change already.  However, since it's not an official release, you would have to compile it yourself (which from your question, seems like something you'd rather not do).  I find the personally find the branch to be very stable, though, and there's been a lot of changes to greatly improve performance, including support of generics.

We've just released 2.9.4 and 2.9.4g, and are about to merge the 3.0.3 branch into trunk.  Not all of the Name ambiguities have been fixed however, though I think the most annoying ones have.  Keep in mind that other methods that were previously marked `[Obsolete]` may have also been removed.  If you want to follow progress on the release of 3.0.3, you can keep checking back to our [website](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/).  The specific issue for CLS Compliance is [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENENET-446), so you can also track the progress on it there.

I'm hoping that we can release the new version very soon and add official support for other .NET languages.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info Christopher. The rollback works just fine for now. I'll pull the nuget update on the next release. I don't mind recompiling, it's just an added step. Is the library hosted on Github? I could pull from there with minimal effort.

Comment: We have a [github mirror](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net) but it's only trunk.  Once 3.0.3 is merged into trunk, it would appear in that repo.  That should happen soon, there's been discussion about it on the mailing list.

Comment: groovy. Since my current project is under version control, I'm not sure if I can pull the lucene project into my main project and run the builds together. I might have conflicting issues with nested projects.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell - Good news, 3.0.3 has been merged into trunk!  I would expect 24 hours before the changes are mirrored on GitHub, though.  Also, it should be known that not all of the solutions in contrib have been updated to work with 3.0.3.  Most have, but a select few haven't, I know at least the `Highlighter` project hasn't, though `FastVectorHighlighter` has.

Comment: This is good news. Once it's merged into Github, how long until nuget is updated?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell - Nuget won't be updated until 3.0.3 is officially released.  I don't know how long that will be.  I'm hoping a month or two, but it could be as late as July.  There are API additions going into 3.0.3 right now, and they're going fairly slow.